# USB 1.0 device not working on USB 3.0

Tags: windows, usb

I have a legacy device that works fine on USB 1.0 or USB 2.0 ports.
However it does not work properly on a USB 3.0 port.

I've tried it on a PC with both USB 2.0 port and USB 3.0 port (it works fine on the 2.0 port on that machine but not on the 3.0 port).

The device installs fine on both, e.g. windows will detect it.

The company who manufactured the device have went out of business so I can't get any updated driver or changes made to the programme.

When I connect it to the USB 3.0 it gives timeout errors.
What I'm guessing is happening is it communicates with the device and waits some time then checks for responses, but maybe because the port is faster the response is coming back before it has even checked for a response and then dies.

I'm wondering is there anyway to slow down my usb 3.0 port or put it in some usb 1 compatibility mode so I can use this device.

Comment: If it doesn't work then there is nothing that can be done. USB 3.0 doesn't actually provide backward support for the earlier revisions of USB this is added by the manufactor of the device itself through the USB cable used. Why can't you just use the USB 2.0 ports?

Comment: Because we have other developers in the office with laptops that only have the new USB 3.0 ports, and also a lot of our customers will buy new computers that only have USB 3.0 ports.

Comment: @Ramhound, are you suggesting that I could use a slower USB cable? Re when you said backword support is added by the manufacturer of the device itself through the USB cable used?

Comment: When a manufacturer releases a USB 3.0 device they have they ability to design it to support both USB 3.0 and USB 2.0.

Comment: Yes but this manufacturer went out of business before USB 3.0 was released, the device is about 10 years old. Does that mean I'm stuffed?

Comment: Try Josh's solution before we determine that.  I still wonder the reason you cannot use the USB 2.0 Port that exists instead.

Comment: @Ramhound, we only have a USB 2.0 Port on one PC. All the new laptops we have purchases only come with USB 3.0. Our customers who also use these legacy USB 1 hardware devices also want to upgrade to laptops that only come with USB 3.0 ports.

Comment: @DernFrench - Your only solution I see is to purchase a USB 2.0 controller card.  There isn't anything the manufacture could do since we are not even dealing with a USB 2.0 device.  It sounds like its a USB 1.1 device which is supports USB 1.0/2.0 ports.

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with a simple card swipe for a POS system(usb 1.0).
I upgraded to a dell AIO Win10 with 4 3.0 ports, card reader would not work in any of the ports, so I'm thinking 1.0 is works with 2.0 and 2.0 work with 3.0,
SO I bought a Manhatten 4 port usb 2.0 hub. Plugged it in, win 10 found it, plugged the card swipe into the usb 20. hub, win 10 found it.
Now the card reader works fine.

bd30907

Comment: Can confirm -- Just chaining in a passive USB 2 hub between the USB 3 host and USB 1 device resolves it completely. (Tested on a PC and a Raspberry Pi.)